# javax.sound.midi library for playing .mid files do not work

Tags: java

I am using below code to play a .mid file from my local system. This code runs in an infinite loop and do not play .mid files. However, no errors are returned.

I tried putting breakpoints also and but couldn't get any clue.

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MidiPlayer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        if (sequencer == null)
            throw new MidiUnavailableException();
        sequencer.open();
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("music.mid");
        Sequence Seq = MidiSystem.getSequence(is);
        sequencer.setSequence(Seq);
        sequencer.start();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

It would be of great help if you can also share some api on java for playing .wma files and .avi files. Because, I need to write code to play all these 3 types of media files i.e. .mid, .wma and .avi

Comment: There is no loop in this code.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why you aren’t hearing music.  The program works for me.  Make sure it’s a valid midi file.  As for the “loop”…

Starting a Sequencer creates a new thread.  The JVM won’t exit until that thread completes.

The easiest way to terminate it is by closing the Sequencer:

```
sequencer.close();
```

However, if you do that right away, the program will exit without playing your music file, since `sequencer.start()` returns immediately, while the music plays on the background thread.

So you will need to wait for your music playback to finish:

```
sequencer.start();

long length = sequencer.getMicrosecondLength();
Thread.sleep(length / 1000 + 1000);

sequencer.close();
```

The sleep time is deliberately approximate.  I ignored the fractional seconds, and added one full second, to account for the possible delay of the playback start.  There are ways to be more accurate than this, but this is probably the easiest approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I am also not sure why it's not being played in my machine while I have tried in my friend's machine and it works perfectly fine.